# Oracle Rows into Columns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

Can someone help me design the query to get below o/p.

Data I have:

```
Table X:
Count Name Amount Days 
5     ABC  500    Day1
10    ABC  1000   Day2
3     BCD  100    Day1
4     BDC  200    Day2
```

Result I need:

```
Name  Count AmountDay1 Count AmountDay2
ABC   5     500         10   1000
BCD   3     100         4    200
```

etc

Is this Possible?

I tried something with the below query, but not getting the desired o/p

```
select * from X
pivot
(sum(amount) for days in ('Day1', 'Day2'))
```

Please help
I'm using Oracle 11 G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to pivot on two columns `Count` and `Amount`, in might be easier to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select name,
  sum(case when days = 'Day1' then "count" else 0 end) CountDay1,
  sum(case when days = 'Day1' then amount else 0 end) AmountDay1,
  sum(case when days = 'Day2' then "count" else 0 end) CountDay2,
  sum(case when days = 'Day2' then amount else 0 end) AmountDay2
from tableX
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb3658/2)

If you want to use the PIVOT function, then you will want to unpivot the two columns `Amount` and `Count`, first:

```
select name, CountDay1, AmountDay1, CountDay2, AmountDay2
from 
(
  select name, col||days as col, value
  from tableX
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ("Count", Amount)
  ) u
) d 
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for col in ('CountDay1' as CountDay1, 'AMOUNTDay1' as AmountDay1, 
              'CountDay2' as CountDay2, 'AMOUNTDay2' as AmountDay2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb3658/10)

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, it worked perfectly to my scneario.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pivot on two columns count and amount:

select * from x
PIVOT
( min(count) as count ,sum(amount)for days in ('Day1', 'Day2'))